# Preferred file extension

Tags: iphone, xcode, file-extension, nskeyedarchiver, saving-data

I am saving with NSKeyedArchiver. What should the file extension of my file name be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only your application can see the files in it's document area, so it's largely irrelevant as long as you're consistent.

That said, I personally tend to use ".data" for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Something that identifies your application unambiguously. Feel free to use more than the usual 3 characters.